# Why isn't this Flexslider working?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, flexslider

I'm kind of confused on this.  I have added the flexslider.css, jquery.flexslider.js, and the jquery initialization in that order into this wordpress yet it is acting as if there is no jquery at all.

http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/framework/

Images just stack on top of each other.  Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think somewhere on the page `jQuery.noConflict` is being called.

Replace the flexslider call with the one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function($) {
      $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
   })(jQuery);

</script>
```